# Why can't you modify attribute of a row directly in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

Lets say I have a dataframe A with attribute called 'score'.
I can modify the 'score' attribute of the second row by doing:

```
tmp = A.loc[2]

tmp.score = some_new_value

A.loc[2] = tmp
```

But I cant do it like this:

```
A.loc[2].score = some_new_value
```

Why ?

Comment: Do you get an error or what?

Comment: Sounds like a typo. For me it works. I have tested this 
`df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B']) \n df.loc[2].A = -1`

Comment: @BERA no error but the dataframe is not updated with some_new_value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be hard to reproduce your case, because Pandas does not guarantee, when using **chained indexing**, whether the operation will return a `view` or a `copy` of the dataframe.

When you access a "cell" of the dataframe by

```
A.loc[2].score
```

you are actually performing two steps: first `.loc` and then `.score` (which is essentially chained indexing). The Pandas documentation has a nice post about it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy).

The simplest way to prevent this is by consistently using `.loc` or `.iloc` to access the rows/columns you need and reassigning the value. Therefore, I would recommend always using either

```
A.loc[2, "score"] = some_new_value
```

or

```
A.at[2, "score"] = some_new_value
```

This kind of indexing + setting will be translated "under the hood" to:

```
A.loc.__setitem__((2, 'score'), some_new_value) # modifies A directly
```

instead of an unreliable chain of `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I tried @user2640045's code and it did indeed work so I was very confused as to why the same thing didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's show an example:

```
import pandas as pd
dict_ = {'score': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'other':'a'}
A = pd.DataFrame(dict_)
A
```

Dataframe:

```
    score   other
0   1       a
1   2       a
2   3       a
3   4       a
4   5       a
5   6       a
```

Now you can do the following, and the values are actually saved:

```
A.loc[2,'score'] = 'Heyyyy'
A
```

Dataframe:

```
    score   other
0   1       a
1   2       a
2   Heyyyy  a
3   4       a
4   5       a
5   6       a
```